# How to leave a cloth forever in the fold position

Tags: timeline

After creating a cloth, I want to leave it in a folding position, without being dependent on a timeline. That is, the cloth will be like another hard object in the form of a fold, and there will be no movement in the cloth when the timeline is activated. How do you do that?

Comment: you can go into the Modifiers panel and apply the Cloth modifier, but you won't be able to animate it, so maybe keep the original version in a collection

Comment: But it does not give me the possibility of apply. Only
apply as shape key What does it mean?

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/